# Is it possible that a C# method parameter of some kind of int can accept null and can update argument

Tags: c#, parameters, reference, int, nullable

As below code expressed, I want SomeMethod

- Have a parameter of some kind of int
- can accept null as parameter
- if parameter is none null, it will use it's value, then update the value of argument variable in Caller2

  ```
  void Caller1()
  {
      SomeMethod(null, ...);
  }

  void Caller2()
  {
      int argument = 123;
      SomeMethod(argument, ...);
      Debug.Assert(argument == 456);
  }

  void SomeMethod(SomeKindOfInt parameter, ...)
  {
      if (parameter != null)
      {
          // use the value of parameter;
          parameter = 456; // update the value of argument which is in Caller2
      }
  }
  ```

Tried and declare:

- **ref int** can't accept null
- **int?** can't update argument in caller
- Create a custom Wrapper class of int did this, but is there a light way or does C# or .net have some build in tech?
- It's not good to split it into two methods because there's a big logic inside which is common whenever parameter is null or none null.

Comment: Why don´t you use a return value in your method?

Comment: How about `ref int?` ?

Comment: @ Jehof, Thank you, int? parameter and together with return value solve my problem

Comment: @dotctor, Thank you, ref int? can do this but it doesn't accept literal SomeMethod(null, ..) , it need to call like this: int? unused = null; SomeMethod(ref unused). In my individual case, I prefer Jehof's solution. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Almost there, you can use `int?` to allow null value **and** put the `ref` keyword.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? test1 = null;
    SomeMethod(ref test1);
    Console.WriteLine(test1);
    // Display 456

    int? test2 = 123;
    SomeMethod(ref test2);
    Console.WriteLine(test2);
    // Display 123

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void SomeMethod(ref int? parameter)
{
    if (parameter == null)
    {
        parameter = 456;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, ref int? can do this but it doesn't accept literal SomeMethod(null, ..) , it need to call like this: int? unused = null; SomeMethod(ref unused). In my individual case, I prefer Jehof's solution. Thank you anyway.